# How to measure coverage on all my source code with #webpack?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, webpack, mocha.js, karma-runner

I'm using Webpack + JS + mocha + karma + ... I need the coverage measurement on all my code, but all I can get, is the coverage only for tested source files...

A sample and the question is here : 
https://github.com/xnopre/test-full-coverage-with-webpack

Thanks for you halp,

Xavier

Answer (score 0):

Using istambul, you can add the areas of the code you want to create a coverage report in your karma.conf.js in the preprocessors section like this:

```
preprocessors: {
        'dist/app/**/**.js': ['coverage'],            '
        'dist/test/**/**.js': ['coverage'],
    },
```

Don't miss adding the '['coverage']' tag after your import :)

Comment: Look at my example, I'm using Webpack, the preprocessor section in on the loadtests.js that is loading all *.spec.js...